# Why do't the resolver threads shutdown in apache Felix

Tags: osgi, threadpool, apache-felix, resolver

I'm trying to embed Felix in Embedded Tomcat. Everything works fine. However when shutting down the Felix framework (have deployed SCR, cm, event admin, and metatype services) it will give me a framework shutdown event. But the threads is still alive in the ResolveImpl executor.

So I've got a bunch of "FelixResolver-" threads still dangling. I cannot force the shutdown of the threads since they belong to the executor.

Shutdown sequence:

```
framework.stop();
final FrameworkEvent fe = framework.waitForStop(wait);
```

and I get

```
fe.getType() == FrameworkEvent.STOPPED.
```

Felix Framework is 'org.apache.felix.framework-5.6.1.jar'

I'm using the following felix bundles:

- org.apache.felix.configadmin-1.8.14.jar
- org.apache.felix.eventadmin-1.4.8.jar
- org.apache.felix.log-1.0.1.jar
- org.apache.felix.metatype-1.1.2.jar
- org.apache.felix.scr.compat-1.0.4.jar
- org.apache.felix.scr-2.0.8.jar

I manually install and start the bundles. I'm not stopping the bundles, instead I stop the framework bundle using the above.

Install order (start order is the same after installing):

- org.apache.felix.configadmin [version 1.8.14]
- org.apache.felix.eventadmin [version 1.4.8]
- org.apache.felix.log [version 1.0.1]
- org.apache.felix.metatype [version 1.1.2]
- org.apache.felix.scr [version 2.0.8]
- org.apache.felix.scr.compat [version 1.0.4]

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,
 Mario

**EDIT 1:**

I've upgraded to felix framework 5.6.2 but the issue still remains.

Comment: File a bug on Felix, this is not a stackoverflow question?

Comment: OK I'll do that, thanks!

Comment: Did you file a bug? Can you give me a link to the bug tracker please?

Comment: Sorry, no I didn't

Comment: I also see this problem on Felix 6.0.1. However, the threads are daemon threads, so they don't stop the VM from shutting down. In my case, I was starting the Felix framework from a class invoked from maven-exec-plugin:java, and the build was hanging for 15 seconds while the plugin waited for threads to shut down. Adding `<cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>` to the plugin config resolved the problem. But it seems to me like a bug in Felix.